# For loop print to line n per column

Tags: python, for-loop, multiple-columns

I have seen previous examples where there are data input. However, here is another case where there is no data but we generate the data instead using for loop.

```
for i in range(1,31):
  print "Hello world"
```

That for-loop probably won't work as I'm new to Python. But the idea is that that will print "Hello world" 30 times in one column.

How can we achieve the output in 3 parallel columns, e.g., 10 lines/rows in each?

```
Hello world 1    Hello world 11   Hello world 21
Hello world 2    Hello world 12   Hello world 22
Hello world 3    Hello world 13   Hello world 23
Hello world 4    Hello world 14   Hello world 24
Hello world 5    Hello world 15   Hello world 25
Hello world 6    Hello world 16   Hello world 26
Hello world 7    Hello world 17   Hello world 27
Hello world 8    Hello world 18   Hello world 28
Hello world 9    Hello world 19   Hello world 29
Hello world 10   Hello world 20   Hello world 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
    print ("Hello World\t\t" * 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

A much easier way to do this would be using a nested for loop.  Something like the following:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        for j in range(3):
                print 'Hello world\t\t',
        print ''


Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world     
Hello world     Hello world     Hello world
```

Comment: If you print the value of i, you'd see

    Hello world 0     Hello world 0
    Hello world 1     Hello world 1
    Hello world 2     Hello world 2
    ...                       ...
    Hello world 9     Hello world 9

How does one distribute the data into columns by specifying n rows per column?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation:

```
for i in range(10):
    print '\t\t'.join(["hello world"] * 3)
```

Comment: I like this the best because it doesn't append `\t\t` to the end of the output.

Comment: `print '\t\t'.join('Hello World' for j in range(3))`

Comment: Nice one! But doing this means duplicating the generated result in the first column 2 more times to get 3 columns in total.

But if we generate 30 rows, what should be done different so that it prints and distribute [evenly] into 3 columns, or 5 columns (with 6 rows in each)?

Comment: @dat789 It's very easy, you only have to change the `range(10)` by the number of rows you need and then replace the `* 3` by the number of cols.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **print one value** to **three column**, you can use a `for` statement and **Print property** to write, As follows :

```
column count = 3
for i in range(10):
   print ('Your Writing     ' * column count)
```

And if you want write three value different is better use bellow code In general, nested loops are better.

```
 for i in range(row-count):
    for j in range(column-count):
            print 'Your text',
    print ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Even a one-liner is possible:

```
print(*['\t'.join(['Hello World!'] * 3) for i in range(10)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Without duplicating the column, how to distribute the following into 3 columns? 
#begin code
for i in range(161,200):
 print "Command: print unichr(%d) = " % i + unichr(i)